# Pulling data from MySQL database and pulling only 1 value of each in a column and then show latest first

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

What I'm trying to do.

To pull data from a database. With one column 'serial_no' to only pull 1 of each value so it's unique, and any other values within the 'serial_no" column to not show if another one of the same value exists. So in column 'serial_no' there could be 35k values but it would only show 35 if there are a total of 35 unique serial numbers. Once I have them I need them to show the latest first by 'datetime' column.

Current outcome.

I have the data pulling through, and it's only showing once of each 'serial_no' however, it's not showing the latest first, like it seems to be ignoring the ordering or just pulling through the first one it sees rather than the latest.

These 2 PHP queries I have used and working but not 100% how it should. The first one, i only want 'serial_no" distinct not all columns, so maybe that's why this one is not working.

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT serial_no, datetime FROM wp_clicker_data ORDER BY datetime DESC";
```

The other one which works fine apart from it does not show the latest value of a specific serial_no

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM  wp_clicker_data GROUP BY serial_no ORDER BY datetime DESC";
```

Any ideas how each unique value of column 'serial_no' can pull through the latest entry based on the latest 'datetime' column?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use Max and GROUP BY to get your desired output as below-

```
SELECT serial_no, 
MAX(datetime) 
FROM wp_clicker_data 
GROUP BY serial_no
```

Comment: This brings back all dates to 01-01-1970 01:00:00

Comment: It should return the latest date per serial id. Id this is not happening, please post some sample data by editing your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the latest row for each serial number, then use filtering:

```
select cd.*
from wp_clicker_data cd
where cd.datetime = (SELECT MAX(cd2.datetime)
                     FROM wp_clicker_data cd2
                     WHERE cd2.serial_no = cd.serial_no
                    );
```

`GROUP BY` is not appropriate when you want to retrieve entire rows.  Using `SELECT *` with `GROUP BY` doesn't make sense, because there are columns in the `SELECT` that are not in the `GROUP BY`. And this construct generally won't work (with the default settings) in the more recent versions of MySQL.

Comment: Just tried this, didn't seem to work? What is cd. and cd2?

Comment: @Nathe . . . Those are table aliases, an important part of SQL.  What do you mean by "didn't seem to work"?  This should be returning the most recent record for each `serial_no`, which is what your question appears to be asking for.